# Is the phrase "has got" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Does "Mary's Got Talent" mean "Mary Has Got Talent"? Is "has got" grammatically correct in this instance?

Comment: You mean, is "America's Got Talent" correct?

Comment: Why, do you suggest, it might not be?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Wrong dupe: *has got* is not "simple past tense". It’s the present prefect construction which uses a present-tensed flavor of *have* and the past participle.

Comment: @tchrist Irene's answer there covers this. The verb phrase _have got_ for _possess_, mainly used in the UK (I've got a horse / car / cold / sneaking suspicion ...).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth **Everybody** says *have got* for possess, Edwin. This is not a UK thing. I cannot imagine why you think it is.

Comment: These Google Ngrams for 'I have flu / I've got flu' show that different preferences exist: [American English corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+have+flu%2CI%27ve+got+flu&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20have%20flu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27ve%20got%20flu%3B%2Cc0); [British English corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+have+flu%2CI%27ve+got+flu&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20have%20flu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27ve%20got%20flu%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @tchrist Alex Gooch at [BBC World Service Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page46.shtml) writes: <<Also, in Britain we often use 'have got' or 'has got' when we talk about possession, while Americans generally just use 'have' or 'has'. 


So, for example, in American English we might say: 
"I have a new car." 

In British English it's more normal to say: 
"I've got a new car." >>

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You’ve got to be kidding me: people say *“I’ve got”* ***all the time*** here. Honest. See [this ngram](http://goo.gl/kjCKne), but you’ll have to hit the search button yourself because they’re decoding the URI wrong.

Comment: ...The verb phrase _have got_ for possess, certainly the vastly preferred informal option in the UK (I've got a horse / car / cold / sneaking suspicion ...; 'I have a horse' would in most cases sound highbrow / stuffy). Apparently, the usage in the US is more common than some commentators have stated.

Comment: The ngram results don't really prove anything, as they don't distinguish "have got" (possessive) from "have got to". but ngram shows "have got" declinjng steadily, with 2000 levels less than half of 1940 levels, on both sides of the pond. However, British usage runs about twice that of American usage for any time during that period.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Yes.  (But it's informal.)

Comment: On the other hand, saying _Mary has got talent_ instead of _Mary's got talent_ is emphatic, or at least strangely official. Auxiliaries are contracted wherever possible in colloquial English. As Greg knows even better than I, since he was trained as a phonologist.

Comment: The character limits are there for a reason. Next time, please expound on your answer. We really do want to hear more about it.